# Function calling itself to enumerate nested group memberships

Tags: function, powershell, recursion

So I've been working on a new logon script for our users. It's bascially finished and it works just fine. However, I've coded a function to enumerate nested group memberships and I don't see how it can work the way I wrote it (although it does!).

Code:

```
$Groups = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList #Array for all groups incl. nested
$MaxIndex = 0

#---Adds every group to the array
Function AddGroup($P1)
{
    do
    {
        #---Param
        [String]$ADObject = $P1

        #---Gets all "main" groups of the current user
        $AllGroups = ([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$ADObject").Findone().Properties.memberof

        #---Durchlauf für jede Gruppe
        ForEach($Group in $AllGroups)
        {
            #---Convert
            [String]$GroupSTR = $Group

            if($GroupSTR -ne "")
            {
                #---Get actual group name
                $GroupSTR = $GroupSTR.SubString(3)

                $IndexOfChar = $GroupSTR.IndexOf(",")
                $GroupSTR    = $GroupSTR.SubString(0,$IndexOfChar)

                $Groups.Add($GroupSTR) | Out-Null

                if($MaxIndex -le $AllGroups.Count) { AddGroup $GroupSTR }

                $MaxIndex = $MaxIndex + 1
            }          
        }

        $GroupSTR = ""
    }
    while($GroupSTR -ne "")
}

AddGroup $LoggedOnUser
```

So what I do is I call the function AddGroup with the username of the current user. The script then gets all the main groups in which the user is currently in and goes into a foreach loop for every group found.
It removes the unwanted gibberish of the ouput of the ADSISEARCHER and then adds the clean group name to the array.

Now to also get the nested group memberships, I get the count of all groups of the current AD object. If my index is below this count, it means the current object is also part of other groups and then calls the function again to get those as well.

Now what I don't understand is, how can my function ever count up my index? The index will always be lower or equal the total amount of found groups. Even if it finds zero groups. Therefore it should call the function infinite times but it doesn't.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of $MaxIndex by this method: $script:MaxIndex =  $MaxIndex + 1 ???

Comment: I see you counting up $MaxIndex, but don't see anywhere that you actually use it as a condition for anything. There is no `'while($MaxIndex -le $AllGroups.Count){do stuff}` loop, so the recursion is happening despite your $MaxIndex code, not because of it. Honestly, what it seems to be reading is `if($GroupStr is a group){if(0 -le $AllGroups.Count){Recurse}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find how your code is working, you can use ISE or PowerGUI in debug mode.

In order to solve your problem why don't you use LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN have a look to [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To find all the groups that "user1" is a member of :

- Set the base to the groups container DN; for example root DN (dc=dom,dc=fr)
- Set the scope to subtree
- Use the following filter : (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=user1,cn=users,DC=x)

Here is an sample in PowerShell :

```
$ADObjectDN = ([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$ADObject").Findone().Properties.distinguishedname
$AllGroups =([ADSISEARCHER]"member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$ADObjectDN").FindAll()
```

Comment: works perfectly and in a much simpler way. thanks a lot!